# Has one actor ever played two different characters from Marvel?

Tags: marvel, actors

Has a single actor ever played two separate characters from the Marvel universe? If so, who?

Comment: Basically [loads](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls056287743/); Stan Lee, Shawn Ashmore, Sam Elliott, Chris Evans, Jon Favreau, Ben Foster, Will Yun Lee, Colm Feore, 
Tim Blake Nelson, Ryan Reynolds, Rebecca Romijn, Ray Stevenson

Comment: Bruce Campbell had 3 different character cameos in Toby's Spiderman trilogy. None were heroes, but all were Marvelous.

Comment: @Richard: Ryan Reynolds? I only know that he played Deadpool.

Comment: @Chris - He also played Hannibal King in the runaway hit movie Blade: Trinity

Comment: @Chris You might as well consider the Wolverine Deadpool and the upcoming Deadpool Deadpool two separate characters given how different they are, too.

Comment: Closely related questions: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90015/what-actor-has-portrayed-the-most-comic-book-science-fiction-superhero-character http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37092/actor-with-the-most-comic-book-movie-roles/37100#37100

Comment: @Richard _runaway hit movie Blade: Trinity_. That actually made me laugh out loud. Nice one

Comment: You should be more specific about what you mean by "separate characters" and "Marvel universe".  Does it count if two characters are meant to look or sound the same and are therefore played by the same actor?  If so, do their appearances have to be permanent (twins, clones, etc) or temporary (shapeshifters, holographic disguises, etc)?  Do voice only roles count (AIs, CG characters, animation)?  By "marvel universe" do you mean the Marvel Cinematic Universe, or any performance media based on Marvel characters (Sony or Fox movies, animation, stage shows, etc)?

Comment: I thought unconstrained "list" questions were supposed to be off-topic? Not that this isn't interesting as clearly the community thinks it is.

Comment: I've done another considerable update to [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110793/55866) since posting it. You may want to look at it, as the current accepted answer only brings one example and it isn't even from the Marvel universe.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Chris Evans played Johnny Storm (AKA Human Torch) and Captain America.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have't seen the old fanatastic four movies since the year they came out, had no idea that was Chirs Evans. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: If the question is asking about two MCU characters then that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: +1, but Richard's comment up there has 12. Don't think they would all count, but this answer would be better if it had more than just the one.

Comment: Well The question is: 

Has one actor ever played two different characters from marvel?
Johnny Storm and Captain America are two different characters from marvel.

They where played by the same actor.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo, "Marvel Universe" in the question sounds rather like "Marvels Cinematic Universe" and the FF movies (neither the old ones nor the new ones) are part of that (as the MCU comprises properties Marvel has still the rights to, so this excludes FF, X-Men and a few other characters). I think this is what ibid is hinting at.

Comment: Does Chris Evans playing Loki disguised as Captain America in *The Dark World* count?

Comment: @ibid The Fantastic Four are part of the MCU as of *Multiverse of Madness*, so it counts.

Comment: @StephenS - The characters are now part of the MCU, but not this specific movie.

Answer (score 157):

## In the MCU

<sub>For an extensive list including all the unnamed background characters, see [here](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Actors_with_Different_MCU_Roles). I've chosen to focus just on the characters with memorable roles who I can find pictures of.</sub>

Laura Haddock plays Peter Quill's mother, Meredith Quill (*Guardians of the Galaxy*), as well as a female fan of Captain America in the 1940's (*Captain America: The First Avenger*).
[image]

Damion Poitier played as Thanos (*The Avengers*) and also plays one of Crossbones Henchmen (*Captain America: Civil War*).
[image]

The twin sisters Imogen and Isabella Poynton play Rhomann Dey's Daughter (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) as well as Lila Barton (*Avengers: Age of Ultron*).
[image]

Nathan Fillion plays Monstrous Inmate (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) as well as Simon Williams/Wonderman (*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* deleted scene).
[image]

Douglas Robson plays the Horned Marauder (*Thor: The Dark World*) as well as the dark elf in The Collector's museum (*Guardians of the Galaxy*).
[image]

Seth Green plays Howard the Duck (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) as well as Expo Fan (*Iron Man 2*).
[image]

Joe Russo plays S.H.I.E.L.D. surgeon Dr. Fine (*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*) as well as psychiatrist Theo Broussard (*Captain America: Civil War*).
[image]

Benedict Cumberbatch plays Stephen Strange (*Doctor Strange*) as well as Dormammu (*Doctor Strange*).
[image]

Taika Waititi plays Korg (*Thor Ragnarok*) as well as the right head of Haju (*Thor Ragnarok*).
[image]

Stephen Blackehart plays the Knowhere Dispatcher that Drax incapacitates (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) as well as Brahl (*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*).
[image]

Clem So plays a Kyln Prisoner (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) as well as a Kamar-Taj Disciple (*Doctor Strange*). (Though I can imagine these being the same character.)
[image]

Kenneth Choi plays Howling Commando Jim Morita (*Captain America: The First Avenger*) as well as his grandson Principal Morita (*Spider-Man: Homecoming*).
[image]

Martin Starr plays a student at Culver University (identified in the novelization as Amadeus Cho) (*The Incredible Hulk*) as well as science teacher Mr. Harrington (*Spider-Man: Homecoming*). (Ignoring the novelization, I can can see these being the same character.)
[image]

Michelle Yeoh plays Aleta Ogord (*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*) and Ying Nan (*Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*).
[image: Michelle Yeoh as Ying Nan and Aleta Ogord]

Gemma Chan plays Minn-Erva (*Captain Marvel*) and Sersi (*The Eternals*).
[image]

Patton Oswalt plays the five Koenig brothers (*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*) as well as Pip the Troll (*Eternals*).

[image]

Enver Gjokaj plays Officer Saunders (*The Avengers*) as well as SSR agent Daniel Sousa (*Agent Carter*).
[image]

Bridger Zadina plays bully E.J. (*Iron Man 3* deleted scenes) as well as Mordis (*Inhumans*).
[image]

Tony Curran plays Bor (*Thor: The Dark World*) as well as Finn Cooley (*Daredevil*).
[image]

Matt Gerald plays White Power Dave (*All Hail the King*) as well as Melvin Potter/Gladiator (*Daredevil*).
[image]

Alfre Woodard plays Mariah Dillard (*Luke Cage*) as well as Miriam Sharpe (*Captain America: Civil War*).
[image]

Rob Mars plays an hospital orderly who tried restraining Thor (*Thor*) as well as muscle-for-hire Jerome Zandow (*Agent Carter*).
[image]

Tom Virtue played Thomas Richards, a Roxxon accountant executed by the Mandarin (*Iron Man 3*) as well as a motel clerk (*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*).
[image]

Clancy Brown plays Surtur (*Thor: Ragnarok*) as well as Ray Schoonover/The Blacksmith (*Daredevil*).
[image]

Linda Cardellini plays Laura Barton (*Hawkeye*) as well as Lylla (*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol.3*).
[image]

---

There also are the people who cameo as different roles. (e.g. Stan Lee)

---

### Outside of the MCU, there are plenty more, for example:

Ryan Reynolds plays Deadpool in the 2016 movie *Deadpool*, as well as playing whoever this is supposed to be in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*:
[image]

Comment: I love this answer also. Guardians of The Galaxy is my favorite movie. Didnt realize that Peter Quil Mother was the same chick that flirts with Captain America.

Comment: Good catch! I wonder if this was intentional or not... she's only credited as "autograph seeker" in CA:tFA (according to IMDB) and may very well have "just" been an extra, but now my mental wheels are spinning. Did meeting Captain America get her hooked on "special" individuals causing her to hook up with Peter's father? SO MANY MCU POSSIBILITIES.

Comment: @Scottie - Peter Quill was born in 1980. If his mom was flirting with CA in the 40s, she would have been a very old mother. Her character in GotG didn't look anywhere near that old.

Comment: Yeah, I realised after writing this that the dates completely don't line up, so I choose to believe in a time-travel-related solution that still allows my retcon to work itself out. :)

Comment: Ooh, I didn’t realise they’d recycled actors within the MCU. (Stan Lee obviously doesn’t count because, as we well know, he’s always playing The Watcher.)

Comment: @PualD most of Stan Lee's cameo's either involve him A)not watching or B)interfering. More like an anti-Watcher.

Comment: Thats supposed to be Deadpool on X-Men Origins

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo It doesn't look anything like Deadpool. :)

Comment: @ibid  yeah, thats why that movie really blows.

Comment: How does he not look like deadpool? You don't often see deadpool without a mask.

Comment: @PStag exactly. Also Deadpool has a mouth.

Comment: "Vin Diesel ...will probably also play Black Bolt" 
Wow, if I ever needed a reason to be happy the Inhumans film to be delayed...

I've been campaigning for Russell Harvard, who played Mr. Wrench in Fargo, myself.

Comment: @ibid / PStag: We know he has a mouth, despite the mask, because he just won't shut it. =)

Comment: Is there supposed to be another picture next to Deadpool? It doesn't look like anything to me.

Comment: Extra Points for the right head of Haju - I don't know that one.

Comment: Joe Russo also appears as in End Game in the captain America therapy session

Comment: You say ‘there aren’t so many’, but that seems like quite a few, really.

Comment: @Fivesideddice - This answer grew over time.

Comment: Michelle Yeoh: Aleta Ogord in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 & aunt Jiang Nan in Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings.

Comment: Just a short list...

Comment: Might need an update with Deadpool and the X-men coming into the MCU.

Comment: Wow, that was certainly an exhausting...er, I mean exhaustive list.

Comment: Does Clark Gregg count, having played Coulson and Sarge / Pachakutiq (who admittedly looks identical to Coulson)? Not to mention the LMD Coulson who was also a main character for a season?

Comment: @user25730 - I would say no.

Comment: A new amendment - Nathan Fillion appears in the third Guardians movie as another new character.

Comment: A couple of additions if you feel like it (I don't have time): Joe Russo's role in Avengers: Endgame, and Nathan Fillion's role in GOTG3, giving them both three roles now.

Comment: Nathan Fillion Is Master Karja in 'Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3'

Comment: Taika Waititi is the left head of Haju, which you have cropped out. The right head is Chris Hemsworth.

Answer (score 50):

Ray Stevenson is the Punisher in Punisher: War Zone and Thor's Tight Buddy as Volstagg in Thor.
[image]

Volstagg
[image]

Comment: Those are the same person? Well done, makeup crew!

Answer (score 36):

Ryan Reynolds plays both Deadpool and Hannibal King from *Blade: Trinity*.

[image]

[image]

Also (half-jokingly), Stan Lee has played a character in many of the Marvel movies dating back to *X-Men* in 2000. Some samples are in the image below.

[image]

Comment: The Deadpool one might even count as two; seeing that it's [strongly suggested they're two different characters](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99253/21267)

Comment: I had no idea blade was a marvel character. Upvoted :)

Comment: Stan Lee shouldn't be in this list. He's playing the same character in every move, but the character is taking some human form in that movie ... Still he plays himself - The One Above All Marvel character.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Do you have any quotes or evidence to back that up? Until we see some comment by Marvel that points in the direction of Stan Lee being some omniscient being, and not just a cameo in every movie, I'm going to stick with what we know and not speculation. As of now, [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0498278/#actor) has Stan Lee listed as he is in the credits of each movie, which is the bit part he was playing.

Comment: @ИвоНедев He doesn't play himself, he plays bit characters. For example, in Iron Man, he plays Hugh Hefner, but in Avengers, he is a librarian. In other movies, he plays other characters with different jobs.

Comment: @ИвоНедев You may be interested in: [Is Stan Lee playing the Watcher in all his cameos?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76303/21267)

Comment: There was a movie based around only one Avenger? Who was it? </cheek>

Answer (score 20):

Ben Foster plays both [Spacker Dave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Punisher_characters#Spacker_Dave) in *[The Punisher (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Punisher_(2004_film))* and [Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Worthington_III) in *[X-Men: The Last Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_The_Last_Stand)*.

### Spacker Dave

[image: Spacker Dave - The Punisher (2004)]

### Angel

[image: Angel - X-Men: The Last Stand]

Comment: Rebecca Romijn also appears in The Punisher (2004) as Joan and as Mystique in the original X-Men films.

Answer (score 17):

Enver Gjokaj plays a cop in the first Avengers film and Agent Sousa in the Agent Carter TV show, a role her reprised in *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* final season.[image: Unnamed Cop]
[image: Agent Sousa]

Answer (score 16):

Thinking laterally here, in any of the X-Men movies featuring Mystique, you'll find that several actors play her role in addition to their regular part *in the same film* - every time she disguises herself as one of the other characters.

Answer (score 6):

Josh Brolin also plays Cable in *Deadpool* as well as Thanos in *Avengers*.

Answer (score 6):

**Rebecca Romijn** played Raven Darkhölme / Mystique in *X-Men* (2000), *X2* (2003), *X-Men: The Last Stand* (2006), and *X-Men: First Class* (2011). She also played Joan in *The Punisher* (2004)

**Ron Perlman** played Reinhardt in *Blade II* (2002) and Big Mike / Shop Owner in [*The Punisher: Dirty Laundry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Punisher:_Dirty_Laundry) (2012 short film).

**Norman Reedus** played Scud in *Blade II* (2002) and voiced Frank Castle  / Punisher in *Iron Man: Rise of Technovore* (2013 animated film).

**Tony Curran** played Priest in *Blade II* (2002), Man in Black Agent in *X-Men: First Class* (2011), Bor Burison in *Thor: The Dark World* (2013), and Finn Cooley in *Marvel's Daredevil* (2015) S02E04 "Penny and Dime".

**Leonor Varela** played Nyssa in *Blade II* (2002) and Camilla Reyes in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013) S01E02 "0-8-4".

**Bruce Campbell** played different cameo roles in Sam Raimi’s *Spider-Man* trilogy: Ring Announcer in *Spider-Man* (2002), Snooty Usher in *Spider-Man 2* (2004), and Maître d’ in *Spider-Man 3* (2007). He also voiced the Tutorial Guide in the video games based on the same films, as well as the Xtreme Reporter in *The Amazing Spider-Man* (2012 video game). He played Pizza Poppa in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), also directed by Sam Raimi.

**Jon Favreau** played Franklin "Foggy" Nelson in *Daredevil* (2003) and then Happy Hogan in *Iron Man* (2008) and reprised the role in subsequent MCU films featuring the character.

**Sam Elliott** played Thaddeus "Thunderbolt" Ross in *Hulk* (2003) and Carter Slade / Caretaker in *Ghost Rider* (2007).

**Patton Oswalt** as already stated in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110793/7957), plays the five Koenig brothers in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013) as well as Pip the Troll in *Eternals* (2021). In addition to that, he also played Hedges in *Blade: Trinity* (2004). He also voiced M.O.D.O.K. in *Marvel's M.O.D.O.K.* (2021 stop-motion animated TV series).

**Nicolas Cage** played Johnny Blaze / Ghost Rider in *Ghost Rider* (2007) and voiced Peter Parker / Spider-Man Noir in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018).

**Laurence Fishburne** voiced the Silver Surfer in *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer* (2007), played Bill Foster in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), and voiced [the Beyonder in *Marvel's Moon Girl and Devil Dinosaur*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXkEZU8TqDE) (2023).

**Tim Blake Nelson** played Samuel Sterns in *The Incredible Hulk* (2008) and Dr. Harvey Allen in *Fantastic Four* (2015). He will reprise his role as Samuel Sterns / the Leader in *Captain America: Brave New World* (2025).

**Clancy Brown** voiced Mr. Sinister in *Wolverine and the X-Men: Foresight* (2009), voiced Taskmaster in *Iron Man & Captain America: Heroes United* (2014), played Ray Schoonover / "the Blacksmith" in *Marvel's Daredevil* (2015), and voiced Surtur in *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017).

**Djimon Hounsou** voiced Black Panther in *Black Panther* (2010 animated TV series) AKA *Black Panther: Who is the Black Panther?* He then played Korath in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014) and *Captain Marvel* (2019).

**Olivia Munn** played Chess Roberts in *Iron Man 2* (2010) and Betsy Braddock / Psylocke in *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016).

**Idris Elba** first played Heimdall in *Thor* (2011) and reprised this role in subsequent MCU films featuring the character. He also played Moreau in *Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance* (2011).

**Colm Feore** played Laufey in *Thor* (2011) and Donald Menken in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* (2014).

**Zoë Kravitz** played Angel Salvadore in *X-Men: First Class* (2011) and voiced Mary Jane Watson in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018).

**Hiroyuki Sanada** played Shingen Yashida in *The Wolverine* (2013) and Akihiko (Yakuza boss executed by Hawkeye) in *Avengers: Endgame* (2019). Archive footage of Hiroyuki Sanada from *Avengers: Endgame* was used in *Hawkeye* (2021) S01E01 "Never Meet Your Heroes".

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://ca.news.yahoo.com/oscar-isaac-moon-knight-actors-095948451.html</sup>

**Elena Satine** played Lorelei in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013) and then Sonya Simonson / Dreamer in *The Gifted* (2017).

**Dove Cameron** played Ruby Hale in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* She also voiced Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman / Spider-Gwen in *Ultimate Spider-Man* (TV series) and Gwen Stacy / Ghost-Spider in the animated specials, *Marvel Rising: Chasing Ghosts*, *Marvel Rising: Heart of Iron*, *Marvel Rising: Battle of the Bands*, *Marvel Rising: Operation Shuri* and *Marvel Rising: Playing with Fire*.

**Katy O'Brian** played Kimball in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and Jentorra in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023).

**Andrew Howard** played Luther Banks in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and then played Zane in *Echo* (2024).

**Thomas E. Sullivan** played Nathaniel Malick in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and then played Vickie Tyson in *Echo* (2024).

**Aaron Taylor-Johnson** played Pietro Maximoff / Quicksilver in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (2014) and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015). He will play Sergei Kravinoff / Kraven the Hunter in *Kraven the Hunter* (2024).

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://heroichollywood.com/kraven-the-hunter-star-aaron-taylor-johnson-didnt-care-avengers/</sup>

**Evan Peters** played Peter Maximoff / Quicksilver in *X-Men: Days of Future Past* (2014), *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016), *Deadpool 2* (2018), and *Dark Phoenix* (2019). He also played Ralph Bohner / "Pietro Maximoff" in *WandaVision* (2021).

**Peter Dinklage** played Bolivar Trask in *X-Men: Days of Future Past* (2014) and [Eitri](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Eitri) in *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018).

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://ca.news.yahoo.com/oscar-isaac-moon-knight-actors-095948451.html</sup>

**Nathan Fillion** voiced Monstrous Inmate in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014), and then played Master Karja in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Mikaela Hoover** played Nova Prime's Assistant in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014), and then voiced and performed motion capture work for Floor in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Sean Gunn** played Kraglin and On-Set Rocket in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014) and reprised these roles in subsequent MCU works featuring these characters. He also voiced Young Rocket in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Alan Tudyk** voiced Alistair Krei in *Big Hero 6* (2014) and then played [Redneck #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpBM4JRs1mU) in *Deadpool 2* (2018).

**Jamie Chung** voiced GoGo Tomago in *Big Hero 6* (2014) and *Big Hero 6: The Series* (2017). She also played Clarice Fong / Blink in *The Gifted* (2017).

**T. J. Miller** voiced Fred Fredrickson / Fredzilla in *Big Hero 6* (2014) and played Weasel in *Deadpool* (2016) and *Deadpool 2* (2018).

**Shea Wigham** played Roger Dooley in *Marvel's Agent Carter* (2015) and voiced George Stacy in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Linda Cardellini** played Laura Barton in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015), *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), and *Hawkeye* (2021). She voiced and performed motion capture work for Lylla in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Donald Glover** voiced Miles Morales / Spider-Man in Season 3 of the *Ultimate Spider-Man* animated TV series. He played Aaron Davis / Prowler in *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017). He had a cameo appearance as a variant of Prowler in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Corey Stoll** played *Darren Cross / Yellowjacket* in *Ant-Man* (2015), and then played MODOK in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023). The character is one and the same in the MCU but is two separate characters in the comics.

**Judy Greer** played Maggie Lang in *Ant-Man* (2015) and *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018). She also voiced War Pig in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**David Dastmalchian** played Kurt in *Ant-Man* (2015) and *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018). He then voiced Veb in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023).

**Hayley Lovitt** played a young Janet van Dyne / The Wasp in *Ant-Man* (2015) and *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018). She also played Sage in *The Gifted* (2017).

**Michael B. Jordan** played Johnny Storm / Human Torch in *Fantastic Four* (2015), and then played Erik Stevens / N'Jadaka / Killmonger in *Black Panther* (2018) and *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* (2022).

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/30-hollywood-stars-played-more-slideshow-wp-171338504.html</sup>

**Miriam Shor** played Alisa Jones in the *Marvel's Jessica Jones* (2015) episode *AKA WWJD?*, and also played Recorder Vim in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Chaske Spencer** portrayed Jace Montero in *Marvel's Jessica Jones* (2015). He also played Henry Lopez in *Echo* (2024).

**Karan Soni** played Dopinder in *Deadpool* (2016), *Deadpool 2* (2018) and will reprise the role in *Deadpool & Wolverine* (2024). He voiced Pavitr Prabhakar / Spider-Man India in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Oscar Isaac** played Apocalypse in *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016), Marc Spector / Steven Grant / Jake Lockley / Moon Knight in *Moon Knight* (2022), and voiced Miguel O'Hara / Spider-Man 2099 in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Mahershala Ali** played Cornell Stokes / Cottonmouth in *Marvel's Luke Cage* (2016) on Netflix. He voiced Aaron Davis / Prowler in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023). He made a voice cameo as Blade in *Eternals* (2021). He is set to play Blade in a 2025 *Blade* film.

**Benedict Cumberbatch** played Stephen Strange / Doctor Strange in *Doctor Strange* (2016). He also played Dormammu (motion capture and voice) in the same film.

> Cumberbatch also portrays, uncredited, the villainous entity Dormammu. The actor suggested he take on the role to Derrickson, feeling that having the character be a "horrific" reflection of Strange would work better than just "being a big ghoulish monster". The director agreed, elaborating that the casting implies that Dormammu does not have a normal physical form in his own dimension, and so is simply imitating Strange for their confrontation. To create the character, Cumberbatch provided motion-capture reference for the visual effects team, and his voice was blended with that of another uncredited British actor, whom Derrickson described as having "a very deep voice"

<sup>- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(2016_film)</sup>

**Skyler Samuels** played the Frost Sisters: Esme, Sophie, and Phoebe, in *The Gifted* (2017).

**Matt Damon** played Loki actor in *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017) and *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022). He also played Redneck #1 in *Deadpool 2*.

<sup>Image source: https://ca.news.yahoo.com/oscar-isaac-moon-knight-actors-095948451.html</sup>

[image]

**Ebon Moss-Bachrach** played David Lieberman / Micro  in *Marvel's The Punisher* (2017) and will play [Ben Grimm / the Thing in *The Fantastic Four* (2025)](https://variety.com/2024/film/news/fantastic-four-cast-marvel-studios-1235875766/).

**Daniel Kaluuya** played W'Kabi in *Black Panther* (2018) and voiced Hobart "Hobie" Brown / Spider-Punk in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Ross Marquand** played Red Skull in *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018) and *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), voiced Red Skull, Ultron, and Ultron Sentries in *What If...?* (2021), and voiced Ultron Sentries in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022).

**Benjamin Byron Davis** played Agent Burleigh in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018). He then played Bretelsnort in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023).

**Kathryn Hahn** voiced Olivia Octavius / Doctor Octopus in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and then played Agatha Harkness / Agnes in *WandaVision* (2021). She will reprise her role as Agatha Harkness in the upcoming TV series, *Agatha: Darkhold Diaries* (2024).

**Hailee Steinfeld** voiced Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman / Spider-Gwen in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and then played Kate Bishop in *Hawkeye* (2021). She reprised her role as Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Lake Bell** voiced Vanessa Fisk in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018), Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow in Season 1 of *What If...?* (2021 TV series), and then played Dr. Graham in *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* (2022).

**Brian Tyree Henry** voiced Jefferson Davis in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and reprised his role in subsequent Spider-Verse films featuring the character. He played Phastos / Phil Stoss in *The Eternals* (2021).

**Russell Crowe** played Zeus in *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022), and will play the father of  Sergei Kravinoff / Kraven the Hunter in *Kraven the Hunter* (2024).

**Richard Dixon** voiced Ulysses Bloodstone in *Werewolf by Night* (2022). He then played Robber Baron in *Loki* S02E03 (2023).

**Devery Jacobs** voiced Kahhori in the *What If...?* Season 2 (2023) episodes "What If... Kahhori Reshaped the World?" and "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?". She also played Bonnie in *Echo* (2024).

Note: To keep the list short, I am only including actors who have played live-action Marvel characters. This excludes voice actors who have voiced multiple Marvel characters but have not played any in live-action. I’m also excluding actors who have played multiple Marvel characters due to either shapeshifting or illusions (e.g., shapeshifted Skrulls, Loki when shapeshifted into other characters) or who have played variants of characters in different universes or timelines (e.g., the variants of Doctor Strange, Loki, Kang, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat trivially, there is Patton Oswalt, who has had four different roles (Billy Koenig, Sam Koenig, Eric Koenig, and Thurston Koenig) on *Agents of S.H.E.I.L.D.*

Answer (score 2):

Jon Favreau Plays Froggy Nelson in the movie DareDevil
[image: Jon Favreau Played Froggy Nelson]

He plays Happy Hogan in Iron Man, Iron Man 2, Iron Man 3, Spider-Man: Homecoming, Avengers: Infinity War (deleted scene), Avengers: Endgame, Spider-Man: Far From Home and Spider-Man: No Way Home
[image]