# Which characters have been recast within the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, actors

Which characters in the Marvel Cinematic Universe have been recast? As in one character being played by two different actors.

I'm only asking about works set within the MCU, and not about other Marvel movies.

### Which characters from the MCU have been recast?

Comment: [Related, not dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110792/has-one-actor-ever-played-two-different-characters-from-marvel/110793#110793)

Comment: From the exact opposite perspective, actor Enver Gjokaj appeared as a cop in *Avengers Assemble* before being cast as SSR Agent Daniel Sousa in *Agent Carter*, which makes him the only person to date to play more than one character in the MCU.

Comment: @DrRDizzle see my answer to the related question.

Comment: Dang it! I didn't know about the Quill's mother though, that's interesting.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There have been **five definite recasts** in the MCU thus far:

## Hulk

Originally played by **Edward Norton** in *The Incredible Hulk* and then by **Mark Ruffalo** in subsequent MCU films.

[image]
[image]

## War Machine

Originally played by **Terrance Howard** in *Iron Man* and then by **Don Cheadle** in subsequent *Iron Man* films.

[image]

## Fandral

Played by **Josh Dallas** in *Thor* and then by **Zachary Levi** in *The Dark World*.   (Thanks to @JasonBaker for pointing out this one!)

[image]

## Thanos

For his cameo at the end of the first *Avengers* film, Thanos was played by **Damian Poitier**.  As of *Guardians of the Galaxy*, he is played by **Josh Brolin**.  (Thanks to @Catmann for pointing out this one!)

[image]
[image]

## Howard Stark

Stark has appeared several times in the MCU and has been played by a trio of actors: **Gerard Sanders**, **John Slattery**, and **Dominic Cooper**.

Sanders and Slattery have portrayed Stark in overlapping periods of the character's life — Sanders is shown as Stark throughout much of the character's adult life in a slideshow memorial at the start of *Iron Man*, including his middle-aged years.  Slattery portrays a middle-aged Stark in *Iron Man 2* and *Ant-Man*.  Thus, this is a genuine recasting.

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, the casting of Cooper as Stark should not be counted as a recasting, as Cooper has played a younger Stark (*The First Avenger* and *Agent Carter*) to Slattery's middle-aged Stark.  In particular, Slattery was brought back for *Ant-Man* after Cooper's work in *The First Avenger*.

Similarly, there are flashbacks in *Agents of Shield*, *Agent Carter*, *Daredevil*, and *Jessica Jones* to younger versions of characters — again, these should not count as recasting.  Likewise, I would not count the actors playing the young Thor and Loki in *Thor*, the young Starlord in *Guardians*, nor the body double for the CGI-modified Chris Evans (pre-serum Cap) in *The First Avengers* as recastings.

Comment: Although there are probably more if you count flashbacks; Peggy Carter has been played by at least two actresses by that measure, but I don't think that's in the spirit of the question

Comment: @JasonBaker : Yeah, I discounted Peggy Carter on the basis that it's just a matter of aging across the elapsed decades.

Comment: Though that leads to the semantic question of whether Howard Stark can technically be considered a recast; perhaps Sanders to Slattery is one, but I'm pretty sure we just have three actors playing the man at different times in his life

Comment: @JasonBaker : I just checked Peggy Carter, and it turns out she was only played by Haley Atwell --- they just used CGI to age her for Winter Soldier.

Comment: She was played by Gabriella Graves in a flashback in last week's *Agent Carter*. But if you're going to count that, you need to count a *lot* more characters; Grant Ward, Dottie Underwood, Peggy's brother Michael, Agnes Cully/Whitney Frost, Thor, Loki, and probably loads more I'm forgetting

Comment: @JasonBaker : What was the nature of the flashback?  Wildly different periods of her life?  What about the others?  If they're all like Stark (same man at very different periods), I would ignore those.

Comment: Yeah, wildly different. All flashbacks to childhood, I'm pretty sure

Comment: The Incredible Hulk wasn't part of MCU.

Comment: @pstag ang lee's *hulk* is not part of the MCU. *the incredible hulk* is. not only does [it fit squarely in the official timeline from marvel](http://marvel.com/news/movies/18766/view_the_full_marvel_cinematic_universe_timeline), RDJ shows up in the post credits as tony stark talking about the avengers, and the events are very specifically referenced in [fury's big week](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Avengers_Prelude:_Fury's_Big_Week).

Comment: Also, Tina Minoru. (See my answer.)

Comment: @ibid : Noted!  (I've just upticked your answer.  At some point, I'll update mine to include that info, if that's okay by you.)

Comment: Out of interest why is Edward Norton in but Eric Bana not?

Comment: @Liath : The Eric Bana Hulk film is not considered part of the MCU.

Comment: Red Skull: Hugo Weaving & Ross Marquand (Endgame). Cassie Lang 3x: Abby Ryder Fortson —> Emma Fuhrmann —> Kathryn Newton (Ant-Man & The Wasp: Quantumania). What If…? Iron Man/ Tony Stark - Robert Downey, Jr. —> animated stand-in Mick Wingert; Captain America/Steve Rogers - Chris Evans —> Josh Keaton; Captain Marvel/Carol Danvers - Brie Larson —> Alexandra Daniels; Spider-Man/Peter Parker - Tom Holland —> Hudson Thames; Black Widow/Natasha Romanoff - Scarlett Johansson —> Lake Bell; Drax The Destroyer - Dave Bautista —> Fred Tatasciore; General Ross - William Hurt —> Michael Patrick McGill

Comment: More What If…? Betty Ross - Liv Tyler —> Stephanie Panisello; Obadiah Stane - Jeff Bridges —> Kiff VandenHeuvel; Pepper Potts - Gwyneth Paltrow —> Beth Hoyt; Peter Quill - Chris Pratt —> Brian T Delaney; Shuri - Letitia Wright —> Ozioma Akagha

Comment: Probably not worth mentioning the "What If" ones - animated shows are rarely voiced by the live-action actors, plus the characters in that show are all technically alternate versions of the MCU characters, not the ACTUAL ones we see in live-action films. Red Skull being recast is a definite fit, though.

Answer (score 6):

Thanos was played by someone else for his short cameo in Avengers. Josh Brolin wasn't officially cast until GotG.

Comment: Nice work.  I hope that you don't mind that I've added Thanos to my list, for completeness.  I've explicitly given credit to you.

Answer (score 4):

**Tina Minoru** was played by Linda Louise Duan in *Doctor Strange (2016)*

[image]

In *Runaways*, she will be played by Brittany Ishibashi

> Brittany Ishibashi (“This Is Us,” “Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Out of the Shadows”) as Tina Minoru – a perfectionist “tiger mom.” In her professional life, she is a brilliant innovator and ruthless CEO. Emotionally, she is less confident, often shying away from difficult conversations with her daughter Nico and careful to avoid explicit displays of her feelings.
>   <sub>['Marvel's Runaways' Sets Remaining Cast for Television Project with Hulu](https://news.marvel.com/tv/59437/marvels-runaways-sets-remaining-cast-television-project-hulu/)</sub>

Comment: Runaways showrunner Josh Schwartz confirmed that the two Minorus are two different, unrelated characters.

Answer (score 2):

### Thaddeus E. "Thunderbolt" Ross

William Hurt first portrayed Thaddeus Ross in *The Incredible Hulk* (2008). In *Captain America: New World Order* (2024), Harrison Ford will play Thaddeus Ross.

> Harrison Ford is stepping into the Marvel Cinematic Universe.
>
> The legendary actor will step in as Thaddeus ”Thunderbolt” Ross, replacing the late William Hurt, for 2024’s ”Captain America: New World Order” starring Anthony Mackie.

Source: [Variety](https://variety.com/2022/film/news/harrison-ford-marvel-captain-america-4-william-hurt-1235403286/)

### Red Skull

Originally played by Hugo Weaving in *Captain America: The First Avenger* (2011), he was replaced by Ross Marquand in *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018) and *Avengers: Endgame* (2019).

> Hugo Weaving has said that while he would have been up for reprising
> his role as Red Skull in *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Endgame*,
> Marvel proved 'impossible' to negotiate with.
>
> Weaving was the villain in 2011 movie *Captain America: The First
> Avenger*, and was all up for making a comeback in the final two
> chapters.
> […]
> Instead, actor Ross Marquand, of *The Walking Dead* fame, voices the
> character in *Infinity War* and *Endgame*, in the pivotal scenes on
> Vormir, with the character being rendered in CGI.

Source: [Yahoo!](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/hugo-weaving-says-his-red-skull-wasnt-in-endgame-because-marvel-were-impossible-120122514.html)

[image]

<sup>Image source: [WhatCulture](https://whatculture.com/film/6-more-comic-book-movie-actors-replaced-in-the-sequels)</sup>

### Vanessa Fisk

Ayelet Zurer portrayed Vanessa Fisk, the wife of Wilson Fisk / Kingpin, in *Marvel’s Daredevil* (2015) on Netflix. In *Daredevil: Born Again* (2024), Sandrine Holt will play Vanessa Fisk.

Source: [The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/daredevil-born-again-lands-director-1235346034/)

### Cassie Lang

Originally played by Abby Ryder Fortson in *Ant-Man* (2015) and *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), she was replaced by Emma Fuhrmann (due to a time skip and aging of the character) in *Avengers: Endgame* (2019). Emma Fuhrmann was then replaced by Kathryn Newton in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023).

[image]

<sup>Image source: [Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/ant-man-3-cassie-recast-kathryn-newton-emma-fuhrmann/)</sup>